# How can I edit greyed out Keyframes again?

Tags: keyframes, dopesheet

I'm having some issues that some keyframes in the Action Editor are greyed out and I can't edit them any more. I'm not sure if I accidentally pressed some button, but this has never happened to me before and I've been using blender for some years now.
MAIN PROBLEM:
I can't delete the keyframes, set new ones or do anything, not even more them on the timeline. Anyone having an idea what is wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have *Locked* your keyframes. Press the padlock icon next to the object name to unlock them again:

[image]